# Proving noncompactnes by showing open cover with no finite subcover

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, functions, compactness

Define:

$$S = \{f \in C([0, 1],\Bbb R) : |f(x)| \le 1 \; \forall x \in [0, 1]\}$$

I have an open cover for the set $S$:

$$U_{n} := \{f \in C([0, 1],\Bbb R): |f(0) − f(1/n)| < 1\}$$

for each $n \in \Bbb N$.

Please help me out with showing that this doesn't have a finite subcover. I have the idea that I need to find a sequence of functions which are not covered by this open cover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: First you have to verify that $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ actually *is* an open cover of $S$, if you’ve not done so already; showing that it’s a cover requires using the fact that each $f\in S$ is continuous at $0$. To show that it has no finite subcover, it suffices to show that for each $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is a function

$$f_m\in S\setminus\bigcup_{n\le m}U_m\;.$$

In other words, $f_m$ must be in $S$, and it must satisfy

$$\left|f_m(0)-f_m\left(\frac1n\right)\right|\ge 1$$

for $n=1,2,\ldots,m$. I suggest trying to construct such an $f_m$ by setting $f_m(0)=0$ and making $f_m$ piecewise linear, with the value $1$ at $x=1,\frac12,\ldots,\frac1m$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the part of how to use the continuity of $f$ at $0$ to show that the given cover is actually open?

Comment: @Martin: Continuity at $0$ is used to show that it’s a cover, not to show that each $U_n$ is open. To show that each $U_n$ is open, you need to specify the topology on $S$. Are you using the topology of pointwise convergence?

Comment: $S$ is a metric space with induced metric of sup norm. However, can you please suggest how to use continuity argument to show U is an open cover?

Comment: @Martin: For any $f\in S$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac1n\right)=f(0)$, so $$\left|f(0)-f\left(\frac1n\right)\right|<1$$ for all sufficently large $n$.

Comment: ok Brian, so by continuity at $0$, we can pass to the limit of $f(1/n)$, I understand this part, but my question is how do we say that this is an open cover?

Comment: @Martin: I can’t tell from your comments whether you recognize that there are two separate issues. The argument whose key point I just sketched shows that $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ covers $S$, meaning that every $f\in S$ belongs to at least one $U_n$ (and in fact to infinitely many of them). This has nothing to do with showing that the sets $U_n$ are open. To do that, suppose that $f\in U_n$. Show that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that if $\|f-g\|<\epsilon$, then $\left|g(0)-g\left(\frac1n\right)\right|<1$, and hence $g\in U_n$. This shows that the $\epsilon$-nbhd around $f$ is a subset of ...

Comment: ... $U_n$ and hence that $U_n$ is open. To show that such an $\epsilon$ exists, use the fact that $\left|f(0)-f\left(\frac1n\right)\right|$ is *strictly* less than $1$.

Comment: Thanks Brian, this clarification helps. I can now indeed visualize this open cover

Comment: @Martin: You’re welcome. (I wasn’t trying to be obscure, by the way; I just think that you learn more when you work out at least some of the details.)

Comment: I understand, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take the piecewise functions $f_m$ whose graphs on $[0,1]$ is given by a line segment of slope $m$ from $(0,0)$ to $(1/m,1)$ and then a flat line from $(1/m,1)$ to $(1,1)$.

No matter how many (finitely many) $U_n$'s you take, simply pick an $m$ bigger than all of the chosen $n$'s, then $f_m$ won't be in your cover.

Comment: Thanks Oxeimon, your answer is same as Brian's

Comment: we literally finished writing them like 5 seconds apart.